# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql, date, time, difference

```
<?php

session_start();

@mysql_connect('localhost','jk','') or die('Please Check Username or Password');
@mysql_select_db('jks') or die('error connetcing database');

$qry3="Select ID from fresh_orders";
$id=mysql_query($qry3);

$qry1="Select CurDate from fresh_orders";
$rs=mysql_query($qry1);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$d210=$row[0];
$d21=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($d210));
echo ("  d21 = "),$d21;

$qry2="Select DueDate from fresh_orders";
$rss=mysql_query($qry2);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($rss);

$d71=$row[0];
$d7=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($d71));
echo ("  d7 = "),$d7;



$date1=date_create("$d21");
$date2=date_create("$d7");
$interval=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $interval->format("%R%a days");




$qry="update fresh_orders set DDays='".$interval."' where ID=".$id."";

mysql_query($qry);
echo $qry;
?>
```

Output is as follows:

```
d21 = 2016-07-20 d7 = 2016-07-10 days = -10 days
```

> ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be
>   converted to string

It does calculate the difference properly but can't update in database!
Gives the Fatal error when trying to update in database. Pls Help !

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If this is not legacy code, please look into alternatives to `mysql_*`.  These have been deprecated and have been taken out of PHP 7.  I would suggest you take a look at this line: `$qry="update fresh_orders set DDays='".$diff."' where ID=".$id."";`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to save the result of `date_diff($date1,$date2)` to the database. More specifically, you're trying to build a string (sql) with it.

`date_diff` produces a DateInterval type, which can't be used as a string - that's why you need to call `->format` on it when you `echo` it. You also need to call `->format('%d')` where you're building the sql statement.

Your output probably doesn't say `days = -10 days`, but something like `days = -10ays`. That's because you're formatting the interval in a weird way - take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving a very perfect explanation. I tried correcting errors just as mentioned by you.But still can't update in database. Is there anyway I can do it? 
$date1=date_create("$d21");
$date2=date_create("$d7");
$interval=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $interval->format("%R%a days");